# Django Rest Framework permissions of POST object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm implementing a custom permission class for a Hyperlinked serializer that uses HyperlinkeRelatedFields and such.

The check is very roughly:

```
def has_permission(self, request,view):
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return True

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return False

    if request.user.is_staff:
        return True

    # POST: 'author' is a URL due to serializer being Hyperlinked
    # meaning we have to translate URL to model (like the serializer)
    # to perform the check
    if url_to_user(request.DATA['author']) == request.user:
        return True
```

Given the comment in the code, it seems like it might be better to have the serializer do this check during validation, though that would shift concerns. It's almost like the validation class needs a method that is passed the new object before save() is called on it to check the POST/PUT was acceptable from a permissions point of view rather than cram HTTP/permissions related checks in to the validation in the serializer.

url_to_user is serialization specific, and checks in the validator portion of serializers would be request/http specific rather than just sanity/integrity checks of the new model.

It seems like a common thing to do so i'm curious which route others have taken and if there is a "more correct" approach i'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the comment says `POST`, I'll assume it's just the creation of a new object you're dealing with.

Since the `author` must be the `request.user` there's no need to have this as a writable field. I'd just set the object's author attribute to the current user in `pre_save`.

Similarly if you want to handle `PUT` you can limit the `QuerySet` to the current user too:

```
def get_queryset(self):
  return MyClass.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
```

(Looking at the `request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS` you may need to do this based on request method...)

That way a user cannot create an object not attached to themselves and cannot update one they do not already own.

However, as ever, [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it); there's nothing wrong with the permissions based route. (I'm not sure there's a final answer here.)